# G+ sdk giving login error?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I have implemented [Google Plus Api](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in) and login as it is given in the site. But it is giving problem after login when I click on allow Access as shown below:

[image]

The following message appears :

[image]

My Code is as follows,pls tell me If anything left:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 self.signInButton.delegate = self;
 self.signInButton.clientID = kClientId;
 self.signInButton.scope = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
                            nil];

 SLNetworkAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SLNetworkAppDelegate*)
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 appDelegate.signInButton = self.signInButton;

 share =[[GPPShare alloc] initWithClientID:kClientId];
 share.delegate = self; // optional
 appDelegate.share=share;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
 [[[[share shareDialog]
    setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started"]]
   setPrefillText:@"testing share via google plus"] open];

 // Or, without a URL or prefill text:
 [[share shareDialog] open];
}


In App delegate file:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
 if ([signInButton handleURL:url
           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation]) {
  return YES;
 }
 if ([self.share handleURL:url
         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                annotation:annotation]) {
  return YES;
 }
 return NO;
}
```

Comment: Might be the redirect url you have specified in google plus is mis-matching. Check the redirect url in google plus client application and make sure you assign same url handling in your application plist file

Comment: hello @Sumanth I have not specified redirect url, pls tell me where it can be specified.

Comment: you have created an application in google so you got kClientId there you need to specify redirect url so after authentication safari browser will handle the url and open your application

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to assign redirect uri in your project with your bundle ID like this so after successful authentication your application will be launched from safari if your handle your url properly:

[image]

Place bundle Id as identifier and URLSchemes...

Comment: I have a doubt on setting bundle id for iOS app. My bundle id is just the project name it doesn't have any prefixes like 'com.companyname'. So it says "invalide parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority:". Is there any necessity to add prefix in bundle id.

Comment: Thanks i just set  bundle Id as URLSchemes and its working fine