# iOS Google+ Safari cannot open page because address is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I have two apps one is free and another is paid version. I have implemented google+ share on paid and its working fine. But when I copied code to my free version it doesn't work. I have one Google apis project and added two clients for both iOS apps.

I get "Safari cannot open page because address in invalid" erro after sharing or cancel and it does not open my app.

Please help

I followed all steps defined at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#detecting_if_a_post_was_successfully_shared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this method into your appdelgate

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
NSLog(@"%@",sourceApplication);


// Handle Google+ sign-in button URL.
if ([signInButton_ handleURL:url
           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation]) {
    return YES;
}



 return NO;
}
```

Comment: use of undeclared identifier 'signInButton_', do i need to declare it somewhere in appdelegate's .h file ?

Comment: have you declared in yourviewcontrolle.h file? ... and add class @class GPPSignInButton;  in you view controller

Comment: well, I have a custom button, on its click i give a call, `[signIn authenticate];`
However even after logging in properly , `- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error` isn't getting called.

I have placed `- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}`
in my appdelegate

Comment: Why are you using custom button , you can change images of GPPSignInButton. have you set delgate? i.e.signInButton_.delegate = self;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036837/g-sdk-giving-login-error?rq=1

this helped me :) Cheeerrrrsss...!!! :D

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that you add a URL Type for your app and that it matches the bundle ID of your app. I made a typo in specifying the URL and it took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working.
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_3_add_a_url_type

Answer (score 12):

For this we have to add URL schemes and identifier value in ProjectName - settings tab - info tab - URL Types tab.

Like in the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Yes i added a description with link.first i mentioned in words and after that i provide an image for an example.

Comment: Thanks for Proper correction.Now this is 100% valid Answer.

Comment: Adding identifier and URL Scheme matching project name solves my problem. Thanks!