# Custom URL works in simulator but not on a device

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, custom-url

I went through and followed [this](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) tutorial to use Custom URL. Everything works as expected on Simulator, so when I use safari and hit `myApp://` a dialog pops up asking if I wish to open the app. SO far so good. However, when I installed the app on a device and hit the same thing in safari I get an error saying `Cannot open page. Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.` I tried this enough times, so it's definitely not a typing error. Any help is greatly appretiated.

`.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.xyz.myApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>iOSMyApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I copied my bundle identifier for `CFBundleURLName`.

**ANSWER**: So just before I was about to bang my head on the desk what I found that it's working when I open a new tab in Safari and then hit the app URL. And I have no idea why this happens. Also if you cancel it and then hit the app URL in the same tab again, it will give you an error I mentioned in the question. So the trick is to hit the app URL in a **fresh** tab everytime.

Comment: See the link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080335/ios-google-safari-cannot-open-page-because-address-is-invalid

Comment: @Ved: Thanks, but I have already implemented that method in my AppDelegate

Comment: Can you share this setting of your app? 
http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/urlScheme2g.gif

Comment: @AdnanAsghar: Added.

Comment: Have you checked the  URL Type in Info Tab of your target?

Comment: @AdnanAsghar: It's there. I don't think there has to be anything wrong with the set-up, since it's working in the simulator.

Comment: Change the CFBundleURLSchemes to "com.xyz.myApp"

Comment: @AdnanAsghar: That's what it is now -_-

Answer (score 0):

[image] This setup is working for me. One thing I have to do is close the current tab of safari and open new one and type

> iOSMyApp://

Comment: Did you try this on a device ? Also what OS is the device using ?

Comment: Tested on 
iPhone 5 iOS 10.2.1 and 
iPhone 6s iOS 10.3.2

Comment: Thanks for your time, what I noticed just now is it works if I open a new tab in safari.